# pythoncom.CoCreateInstance can't create IZoneIdentifier; the interface is missing from registry too despite being documented in MSDN

Tags: python, internet-explorer, pywin32, pythoncom, urlmon

I'm trying to implement [Manipulating the zone identifier to specify where a file was download from – The Old New Thing - MSDN blogs](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20131104-00/?p=2753) in Python.

At `CoCreateInstance`:

```python
pythoncom.CoCreateInstance(
        pywintypes.IID('{0968e258-16c7-4dba-aa86-462dd61e31a3}'),    #CLSID_PersistentZoneIdentifier
        None,pythoncom.CLSCTX_ALL,
        pywintypes.IID('{cd45f185-1b21-48e2-967b-ead743a8914e}'))    #IID_IZoneIdentifier
```

I get an error:

```python
TypeError: There is no interface object registered that supports this IID
```

<sub>(No stacktrace as this is an extension function)</sub>

If I replace the `IZoneIdentifier` IID with `pythoncom.IID_IUnknown` or `pythoncom.IID_IPersistFile`, it works, but a `QueryInterface` with the right IID fails with the same error.

Indeed, in `HKCR\Interface`, I see nothing like `IZoneIdentifier` but do see an `IPersistFile`.

---

Having disassembled `urlmon.dll`, I see that it indeed implements the interface, but doesn't register it in its `DllRegisterServer`. Searching further, I see that `IPersistFile` is being registered by `ole32.dll` - but not `IZoneIdentifier`.

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537032(v=vs.85).aspx) documents this interface to be available since IE6. But it's not there in either IE7 or IE8. Since this is XP (and with all the updates allegedly), I've nothing else to try.

Likewise, the interface is present in Windows SDK 7.0 in the `urlmon.h` file mentioned in the MSDN article.

The questions are:

- Was this interface silently dropped in favour of something else without MSDN reflecting that or something? Alternatively, is this a known issue? Is it available in later versions of IE?
- What components do `ole32.dll` and `urlmon.dll` pertain to (so I can try (un)installing updates for them)?

Comment: Not every interface is mentioned in the registry - only those that have marshaling support (the whole point of registering the interface is to tell the system how it's marshaled). Apparently, `IZoneIdentifier` doesn't allow marshaling.

Comment: I would guess that Python needs a type library describing the interface, in order to know which methods it provides. The set of interfaces described in a type library is smaller still than the set of interfaces registered for marshaling.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The original C++ program works. So, it's indeed something wrong with Python's requirements. All that is left is find out what exactly. It's definitely not TypeLib because `pythoncom` can work with late binding just fine. This is quite disappoining, as `pywin32` functions generally strive to be mere pythonic wrappers over the underlying API, with only the minimal necessary amount of additional logic.

Comment: A C++ program doesn't generally require that the interface be described in a type library; a description in a C++ header file (that the program can `#include`) is sufficient. I imagine Python cannot read C++ headers, that's why it needs the description of an interface in a different form. `IZoneIdentifier` is not derived from `IDispatch`, so can't be used via late binding either.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I just now checked: `IPersistFile` is also based on `IUnknown` and not `IDispatch`. So, the answer should ultimately lie in `pythoncom`'s source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `IZoneIdentifier`. The original C++ program runs just fine. As [@IgorTandetnik pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40453455/izoneidentifier-interface-is-missing-from-registry-despite-being-documented-in-m?noredirect=1#comment68156403_40453455), not every interface an object implements is going to be registered in the registry, only those that support marshalling.

The error comes from `pythoncom` itself (a hint is that it's a `TypeError`, not `pythoncom.com_error`, and the error message is always in English rather than the system's UI language).

The cause is that `pythoncom` indeed requires `IDispatch` support by the interface - or it wouldn't be able to deduce how to work with the interface's functions and values they accept/return.

The only exception is a number of `IUnknown`-based interfaces support for which is compiled in (`IPersistFile` is one of them; the full list is in `pythoncom.InterfaceNames` apparently).

Support for other `IUnknown`-based interfaces can be added with a "pythoncom extension" module. Some (very scarce) documentation on them can be found in `pywin32` docs in the [Python and COM - Implementation Details](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/html/com/win32com/HTML/PythonCOM.html) article.